# github is not asking for password while interacting with remote repo, no ssh is setup

Tags: git, github

I do not have ssh setup for my github account on new mac ( 10.12.6 )

On day 1 for first repo which I cloned; github asked for email and password. Later on for any other repo cloning, pushing to remote; it's not asking for credentials.

Is this security bug or am I missing something ?

https://help.github.com/articles/why-is-git-always-asking-for-my-password/, this is not working

Comment: git has a tool called `git-credential` that stores your credentials.

Comment: @Rishav can you please explain in detail, as I was never asked to store credential, if you can give detailed answer with pointers to document; I can accept your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that git is storing your credentials.

Comment: can you please explain in detail, as I was never asked to store credential, if you can give detailed answer with pointers to document; I can accept your answer

Comment: Git might store credentials automatically. Here is a link: [https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store)